# onclick of radio button a dropdown should populate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, onclick, radio-button

I have following code for my advance search form.
When I select a radio button against customer, drop down values should populate with customer data.

```
<div class="container">
 <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
<%= radio_button_tag :customer, params[:customer] %><p>Customer</p>
<%= radio_button_tag :supplier, params[:supplier] %><p>Supplier</p>
 <% end %>
<%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :state) %>
<%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :city) %>
<%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
```

Currently I am facing 2 problems -
1. I am able to select both the radio buttons at the same time. One should be deselected when I select other. How to handle that.
2. On click of radiobutton drop down value should be displayed on the screen.

How to handle both of these?
Also if anyone can suggest a good source of jquery and ajax to learn.

Thanks
Mugdha

I have changed the code like this

```
<div class="container">
    <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'user_type', 'customer' %><p>Customer</p>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'user_type', 'supplier' %><p>Supplier</p>
    <% end %>
        <h2>Search Criteria</h2>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <p>State</p>
        <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :state) %>
        <p>City</p>
        <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :city) %>
        <p>Name</p>
        <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :name) %>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown1">
        <p>State</p>
        <%= collection_select(:supplier, :supplier_number, Supplier.all, :id, :state) %>
        <p>City</p>
        <%= collection_select(:supplier, :supplier_number, Supplier.all, :id, :city) %>
        <p>Name</p>
        <%= collection_select(:supplier, :supplier_number, Supplier.all, :id, :name) %>
    </div>
</div>

<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#dropdown").hide();
            $("#dropdown1").hide();
        $("input[type='radio'][name='user_type'][value='customer']").click(function(){
          $("#dropdown1").hide(); 
          $("#dropdown").show();
        $("input[type='radio'][name='user_type'][value='supplier']").click(function(){
            $("#dropdown").hide();
          $("#dropdown1").show();  

          }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I have to pass the selected values of dropdown and selected radio button to controller so that I can find the values from model which will match search criteria. My question is how to transfer jquery selected values to controller?

Comment: You have to group your radiobuttons using name attribute

Comment: With jQuery questions, it helps to see the output HTML, not the input html/code mix

Answer (score 0):

1. Your radio buttons must have the same name attribute. The easiest way to do this is:

   ```
   <%= radio_button_tag :user_type, params[:customer] %><p>Customer</p>
   <%= radio_button_tag :user_type, params[:supplier] %><p>Supplier</p>
   ```

   I guess that you have customer and supplier boolean attribute on maybe a user model? If that's true, this means that you would have to change this to a user_type field (or something similiar) that contains this information. This is a better solution if you can't be a supplier and a customer on the same time.
2. If i understand you correct, you could do something like this:

   ```
   # In view (could fx. be: app/views/shared/_search_form.html.erb)
   <div class="container">
     <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
       <%= radio_button_tag :customer, params[:customer], :data => {:target => "state_select"} %><p>Customer</p>
       <%= radio_button_tag :supplier, params[:supplier], :data => {:target => ".supplier_selection"} %><p>Supplier</p>
     <% end %>
     <div class="selection customer_selection">
       <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :state, {}, {:class => "state_select"}) %>
       <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :city, {}, {:class => "city_select"}) %>
     </div>
     <div class="selection supplier_selection">
      <%= collection_select(:customer, :customer_number, Customer.all, :id, :name, {}, {:class => "name_select"}) %>
     </div>
   </div>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>

   # In javascript (could fx. be: app/asssets/javascript/shared/search_form.js)
   $(document).ready(function() { 
     $(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(){ 
       $(".selection").hide();
       var target_selector = $(this).data('target');
       $(target_selector).show();
     }); 
   }); 

   # In css
   .selection{
     display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to do something like this. On selection of radio button a dropdown should be displayed with values from customer model or supplier model.                                              <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("hi");
        $('input[type=radio]').live('change', function(){           alert('hello'); });
    });
</script>

Comment: Is the javascript meant to go into a view .js.erb file?

Comment: No all javascript files should be in `app/assets/javascripts` if you are using Rails 3.2 or more. If you use a rails version before assets pipeline (3.1 and less) they should be in `public/asssets/javascripts`. There is also a `assets/stylesheets` folder both places.